# How do I remove the body of a method or constructor with javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

I need to remove the body of constructors and methods w/ a void return type using the javassist library. The following works.

```
ctClass.getConstructors()[0].setBody("int i = 0");
```

But this doesn't

```
ctClass.getConstructors()[0].setBody("");
```

Instead I get this exception

```
compile error: syntax near ""
```

When I try

```
ctClass.getConstructors()[0].setBody(null);
```

I get

```
compiler error: no such a constructor
```

I get the same error when trying to empty a method w/ void return type. Looking through Google and documentation, I can't figure out how to empty out the body without inserting some kind of code and I don't want to add arbitrary code for no reason.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Is that an exercise? In which case just try any valid combination as per http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtBehavior.html#setBody-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javassist replaces a method body with a valid block as the body of a method. A non-statement is not a valid block. You can instead set `{ }` as the method body which is a block. Alternatively, you could also make the implicit `return;` statement explicit.

For a constructor, it is always required to invoke the super costructor or an auxiliary constructor first. An empty block would not be valid.

Comment: It works! I was thinking the same about the constructors, that even if one isn't specified in the source, there still has to be one in the byte-code... but when the methods failed with the same error, I knew there was something more.